# Fortify laravel 10 - login issue on production

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 10 with jetstream +livewire.

in my local host everything is fine, but on server I have an issue.

when I login with wrong credential  it redirect me to home page without error and without login.

I tried to to clear cache, update composer, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the validation error is thrown, to home page.
and i have fixed it by adding this code to `FortifyServiceProvider`

```
    Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $user;
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ])->redirectTo('login');
    });
```

by adding `redirectTo('login')` to the `ValidationException` solves the problem.